# Unable to recieve data on a socket using node js

Tags: node.js, sockets

Below is a simple TCP socket programming in node js:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect(9998, '192.168.0.103');
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

client.write("Hi\n");
client.on('data', function(data)  {
        console.log(data.toString("utf-8")); // Here I received 'hi' as expected.       
});
client.write("I will send file");
client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString("utf-8"));   //Here, I again received 'hi' though expected 'Ok' message.     
});
```

I am receiving the same message on the socket. Can someone help me?

Comment: what is the server code you are connecting to?

Comment: the server code is a java program